# Not able to format data in nested div

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery. Facing an issue while showing records in nested div. The problem is when the inner div is populated it shows in proper formatting and appropriate CSS class is attached, however when next time the inner div populates it doesn't show in appropriate formatting.

first time load
[image]

second time load
[image]

below is the code used to form the nested div.

```
var pidCount = retVal.length;
                for( var x = 0; x < retVal.length; x++ ) {
                    var pid=retVal[x]["PID"];
                    currOpp= retVal[x]["opp"];
                    if (prevOpp!= currOpp){
                        if (x>=0){
                            output += '</ul></p></div>';
                            oppCount++;
                        }
                        output += '<div data-role="collapsible"><h4>' + retVal[x]["oppn"] + '</h4><p><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="pidInner'+x+'"><li data-role="list-divider"></li>';

                    }
                    prevOpp= retVal[x]["opp"];
                    output += '<li><a onclick="RefreshProjectPage('+ pid + ')">'+pid+': '+retVal[x]["pn"]
                    +'<p class="client-detail"><span>Sales Prob : ' + retVal[x]["Prob"] 
                    + ' , Revenue : '+ retVal[x]["Curr"] + ' ' + retVal[x]["Rev"]
                    +'</span></p></a></li>';
                    if (x== retVal.length -1){
                        output += '</ul></p></div>';
                    }

                }
                output += '</div>';
                var div = $("#oppListView");
                div.empty();
                div.append(output);
                $("#oppListHeader").html(pidCount.toString() + " projects in "+ oppCount.toString() +" Opportunities");
                div.find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({refresh:true});

                if ( div.hasClass('ui-listview')) {
                    div.listview('refresh',true);
                     } 
                else {
                    $('#oppListView:visible').listview('refresh');
                     }

                $("#oppListView div div div ul").trigger('create');
```

Thanks,
Rajiv

Comment: can u make a fiddle for ur issue? @ http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Attempted to make jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/GZPXP/3/ its working separately in

Comment: Attempted to make jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/GZPXP/3/ its working separately in HTML file but not working in jsfiddle...i m not able to find the reason but..